# Obejct-C / Xcode Not able to add/change text in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

For some reason, i'm not able to change or add text in my UITextView from code.

I have made Outlet and connected (All in IB) - nothing happens.
Even tried to add -setNeedsDisplay
Do i need to set some property ? - This i driving me nuts....

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {
    UITextView *textInfoView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textInfoView;


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    textInfoView.text = @"Test";
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    textInfoView.text = @"Test";    
    textInfoView.text = [textInfoView.text stringByAppendingString:@"Line2"];
    [textInfoView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPS - Got it...

Forgot to @synthesize...

For some reason i did not get warning or "setter error" in Xcode 4.4, maybe it's a version bug ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, really strange that this code doesn't update the text inside the UITextView. I have tried and it works for me ... I think that you don't have correctly linked the Outlet in interface builder, or you don't have associated your view controller to your view ...

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running ? I have version 4.4 and updated just about a week ago...